# If $I\subseteq J$ are ideals of $R$ then $R/J\subseteq R/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can somebody help me figure this one out?

**Question 1** - Let $R$ be a ring and let $I\subseteq J$ be ideals of $R$. Then is it true that $R/J \subseteq R/I$?

**What I have done** - I can define a map $\phi:R/J\to R/I$ by $r+J\mapsto r+I$

Then this map is injective because $$\phi(r_1)=\phi(r_2)\Longrightarrow r_1+I=r_2+I\Longrightarrow r_1-r_2\in I\subseteq J\Longrightarrow r_1+J=r_2+J$$

But I don't know why this is well defined. Can someone tell me what to do?

If $r_1+J=r_2+J \Rightarrow r_1-r_2\in J$  Why should it be in $I$?

**EDIT** -

**Question 2** - In general is there any relation between $R/J$ and $R/I$ when $I\subseteq J$?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a surjective map $R/I\to R/J$, whose kernel is $J/I$. That's as good as it gets.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong from the beginning: you *cannot* define a map $R/J\to R/I$ by $r+J\mapsto r/I$ *for all $r\in R$*. Take for instance $R=\Bbb Z$, $I=6\Bbb Z$ and $J=2\Bbb Z$. Then you are saying for instance that $1+J\mapsto 1+I$ and $3+J\mapsto 3+I$, but that is contradictory because $1+J=3+J$ is the same element of $R/J$, but $1+I\neq3+I$ are distinct elements of $R/I$.

In fact it is false that $R/J$ is contained in $R/I$ simply because classes in $R/J$ are not also classes in $R/I$. But one could define an injective map $R/J\to R/I$ by requiring $r+J\mapsto r/I$ for $r$ in *some* complete set of representatives of $R/J$, which one needs to specify. The resulting map will depend on that choice.

Comment: That is a good point. Thank you @Marc van Leeuwen

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for it to be in $I$. For example, suppose that $r_1=0$ and $r_2$ is an element of $J$ which is not in $I$.

For an extreme case, you can take $I=0$. Then you are trying to show that $R/J$ is contaned in $R$, and it generally is not. For example, when $R=\mathbb Z$ and $J=(2)$.

Comment: So in general $I\subseteq J$ does not imply $R/J\subseteq R/I$?